# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x88a6fd

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider, simplecursoradapter

I'm beginner and I'm trying to to load contact from database by clicking a button in a fragment, and then save outgoing call also in database?
**ContactsFragemt.java**

```
public class ContactsFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>
{

SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact, container, false);
    final Button Button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.load_button);
    final SQLDataBaseAdapter sqlDataBaseHelper = new SQLDataBaseAdapter(getActivity());


    //*************************** method for population main contacts listView *********************************//

    Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Cursor c = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                String contactName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                String phNumber = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                String image_uri = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI));


                int position = 0;
                int exist = 0;
                boolean imageComp, nameComp;
                String[] contactsData = sqlDataBaseHelper.getContacts(position);
                while (exist == 0 && (contactsData[0] != (null) || contactsData[1] != (null) || contactsData[2] != (null))) // we are checking that if it is reached at the end or not
                {
                    if (contactsData[1] != null) {
                        if (contactsData[1].equals(phNumber))  // will make update if we got matched with phone number and if any of ther other parameter is changed
                        {
                            if (contactsData[2] == null) {
                                // pic is null saved in data base and
                                if (image_uri != null) {
                                    sqlDataBaseHelper.updateTable1(null, null, null, null, contactsData[2], image_uri);
                                    // then update new pic here
                                }
                            } else // but if their is pic
                                if (!contactsData[2].equals(image_uri)) { // and he/she update pic with a brand new picture then
                                    sqlDataBaseHelper.updateTable1(null, null, null, null, contactsData[2], image_uri);
                                }
                            if (contactsData[0] == null) {
                                // name is null saved in data base and
                                if (contactName != null) {
                                    sqlDataBaseHelper.updateTable1(contactsData[0], contactName, null, null, null, null);
                                    // then update new name here
                                }
                            } else  // if name was saved previously in based
                                if (!contactsData[0].equals(contactName)) {   //but the guy changed his name so
                                    sqlDataBaseHelper.updateTable1(contactsData[0], contactName, null, null, null, null);
                                }
                            exist = 1;
                        }
                    }
                    position++;
                    contactsData = sqlDataBaseHelper.getContacts(position);
                }
                if (exist == 0)  // means if number is not in the list then make update
                {

                    long id = sqlDataBaseHelper.insertData1(contactName, phNumber, image_uri);
                    if (id < 0) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Data1 Insertion is unsuccessful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Data1 Insertion is successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }

            String[] fromFieldNames = sqlDataBaseHelper.fromFieldName1();
            int[] toViewIDs = sqlDataBaseHelper.toIds1();
            adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
                    R.layout.list_items_view,
                    null,
                    fromFieldNames,
                    toViewIDs,0);
            ListView mainList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.main_list_view);
            mainList.setAdapter(adapter);
            getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, ContactsFragment.this);

        }

    });
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    Uri uri = ContentProvider.CONTENT_URI;
    return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), uri, null, null, null, null);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    adapter.swapCursor(data);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader loader) {
    adapter.swapCursor(null);
}



}
```

***SimpleCursorAdapter.java***

```
public class SimpleCursorAdapter extends android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter {

Context mcontext;
String[] values;
Cursor cursor;
int[] to;

public SimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to);
    this.values = from;
    this.to = to;
    this.cursor = c;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mcontext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(list_items_view, parent, false);
    final ImageButton call = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.call);
    ImageButton sms = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.sms);
    final TextView contact_no = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_no);
    final TextView contactName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_name);
    ImageView contactImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_image);

    final SQLDataBaseAdapter sqlDataBaseHelper = new SQLDataBaseAdapter(mcontext);


    //********************************** method for calling from app****************************/

    call.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {    //when phone button is clicked
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(String.valueOf("tel:" + contact_no.getText().toString())));
            callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);//*/
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mcontext, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            mcontext.startActivity(callIntent);//*/

            Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();
            int hourOfDay = rightNow.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            String AM_PM;

            if (hourOfDay > 12) {   // for 12 hours format
                hourOfDay = hourOfDay - 12;
                AM_PM = "PM";
            } else {
                AM_PM = "AM";
            }

            String time = Integer.toString(hourOfDay)
                    + " : " + Integer.toString(rightNow.get(Calendar.MINUTE))
                    + " " + AM_PM;

            String date = Integer.toString(rightNow.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
                    + "/" + Integer.toString(rightNow.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1)
                    + "/" + Integer.toString(rightNow.get(Calendar.YEAR));

            String name = contactName.getText().toString();
            Cursor c = mcontext.getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

            if (c.moveToNext() == true) {
                String duration = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION));
                String pic = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.asim.simpleviewpager/drawable/outgoing_call.png").toString();
                long id = sqlDataBaseHelper.insertData2(name, duration, pic, time, date);
                if (id < 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(mcontext, "Data2 Insertion is unsuccessful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(mcontext, "Data2 Insertion is successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            c.close();
        }
    });

    //********************************** method for sending message from app****************************//

    sms.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {     //when sms button is clicked
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("sms:" + contact_no.getText().toString()));
            smsIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            mcontext.startActivity(smsIntent);
            Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();
            int hourOfDay = rightNow.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            String AM_PM;

            if (hourOfDay > 12) {
                hourOfDay = hourOfDay - 12;
                AM_PM = "PM";
            } else {
                AM_PM = "AM";
            }

            String time = Integer.toString(hourOfDay)
                    + " : " + Integer.toString(rightNow.get(Calendar.MINUTE))
                    + " " + AM_PM;

            String date = Integer.toString(rightNow.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
                    + "/" + Integer.toString(rightNow.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1)
                    + "/" + Integer.toString(rightNow.get(Calendar.YEAR));

            String name = contactName.getText().toString();
            String duration = "000 000 000";
            String pic = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.asim.simpleviewpager/drawable/message_sent.png").toString();
            long id = sqlDataBaseHelper.insertData2(name, duration, pic, time, date);
            if (id < 0) {
                Toast.makeText(mcontext, "Data2 Insertion is unsuccessful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(mcontext, "Data2 Insertion is successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    });
    //************************** Reading contact from SQLDataBase for each item*************************************//

     String[] contactsData = sqlDataBaseHelper.getContacts(position);
    if (contactsData[0] != (null)) {

        contactName.setText(contactsData[0]);
        contact_no.setText(contactsData[1]);
        if (contactsData[2] == (null)) {
            contactImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.w4j8n);
        } else {
            contactImage.setImageURI(Uri.parse(contactsData[2]));
        }
    }//*/

    return view;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

}
}
```

**ContentProvider.java**

```
public class ContentProvider extends android.content.ContentProvider {

public static final String PROVIDER_NAME = "com.example.asim.simpleviewpager";  //.contentprovider
public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + PROVIDER_NAME + "/ContactsDataBase");
private static final int CONTENTPROVIDERS = 1;
private static final UriMatcher uriMatcher ;
static {
    uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
    uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, "ContactsDataBase", CONTENTPROVIDERS);
}

SQLDataBaseAdapter sqlDataBaseAdapter;
@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    sqlDataBaseAdapter = new SQLDataBaseAdapter(getContext());
    return true;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {

    if (uriMatcher.match(uri) == CONTENTPROVIDERS) {
        return sqlDataBaseAdapter.getAllContacts();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

@Nullable
@Override
public String getType(Uri uri) {
    return null;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    return 0;
}
}
```

**SQLDataBaseAdapter.java**

```
public class SQLDataBaseAdapter {

SQLDataBaseHelper sqlDataBaseHelper;

public SQLDataBaseAdapter(Context context){
    sqlDataBaseHelper = new SQLDataBaseHelper(context);
}
public long insertData1(String contactName, String contactNo, String pic){

    SQLiteDatabase db = sqlDataBaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues =  new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(SQLDataBaseHelper.NAME, contactName);
    contentValues.put(SQLDataBaseHelper.NO, contactNo);
    contentValues.put(SQLDataBaseHelper.PICTURE, pic);
    long id = db.insert(SQLDataBaseHelper.TABLE1_NAME,null,contentValues);
    return id;
}
public long insertData2(String contactName, String duration, String time, String date, String pic ){

    SQLiteDatabase db = sqlDataBaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues =  new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(SQLDataBaseHelper.NAME, contactName);
    contentValues.put(SQLDataBaseHelper.DURATION, duration);
    contentValues.put(SQLDataBaseHelper.TIME, time);
    contentValues.put(SQLDataBaseHelper.DATE, date);
    contentValues.put(SQLDataBaseHelper.PICTURE, pic);
    long id = db.insert(SQLDataBaseHelper.TABLE2_NAME,null,contentValues);
    return id;
}
public String[] getContacts(int position) {
    String[] contactsData = new String[3];
    SQLiteDatabase db = sqlDataBaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] columns = {SQLDataBaseHelper.UID, SQLDataBaseHelper.NAME, SQLDataBaseHelper.PICTURE, SQLDataBaseHelper.NO};
    Cursor cursor = db.query(SQLDataBaseHelper.TABLE1_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToPosition(position);
    int pos = cursor.getPosition();
    int cnt = cursor.getCount();
    int checkElement = cnt-pos;
    if (checkElement > 0)  
    {
        cursor.moveToPosition(position); 
        int nameColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLDataBaseHelper.NAME);
        String name = cursor.getString(nameColumnIndex);
        int noColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLDataBaseHelper.NO);
        String contactNo = cursor.getString(noColumnIndex);
        int picColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLDataBaseHelper.PICTURE);
        String picture = cursor.getString(picColumnIndex);
        contactsData[0] = name;
        contactsData[1] = contactNo;
        contactsData[2] = picture;
    } else   
    {
        contactsData[0] = null;
        contactsData[1] = null;
        contactsData[2] = null;
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return contactsData;
}
public void updateTable1 (String oldName, String newName, String oldPhoneNo, String NewPhoneNumber, String oldPic, String newPic) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = sqlDataBaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    if (oldName != newName) { 
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(SQLDataBaseHelper.NAME, newName);
        String[] whereArgs = {oldName};
        db.update(SQLDataBaseHelper.TABLE1_NAME,contentValues,SQLDataBaseHelper.NAME+" =? ",whereArgs);
    }
    if(oldPhoneNo!=NewPhoneNumber){
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(SQLDataBaseHelper.NO, NewPhoneNumber);
        String[] whereArgs = {oldPhoneNo};
        db.update(SQLDataBaseHelper.TABLE1_NAME,contentValues,SQLDataBaseHelper.NO+" =? ",whereArgs);
    }
    if(oldPic!=newPic){
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(SQLDataBaseHelper.PICTURE, NewPhoneNumber);
        String[] whereArgs = {oldPic};
        db.update(SQLDataBaseHelper.TABLE1_NAME,contentValues,SQLDataBaseHelper.PICTURE+" =? ",whereArgs);
    }

}
public void deleteRowTable1()
{

}
public void updateTable2 ()
{

}
public void deleteRowTable2()
{

}


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
public Cursor getAllContacts(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = sqlDataBaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.query(SQLDataBaseHelper.TABLE1_NAME, new String[] {
                    SQLDataBaseHelper.UID,SQLDataBaseHelper.NAME, SQLDataBaseHelper.NO, SQLDataBaseHelper.PICTURE},
            null, null, null, null,
            SQLDataBaseHelper.NAME + " asc ");
}


public SQLDataBaseAdapter open() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = sqlDataBaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}
public Cursor getAllRows1() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = sqlDataBaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(true, SQLDataBaseHelper.TABLE1_NAME, SQLDataBaseHelper.ALL_KEYS1, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return cursor;
}


public String[] fromFieldName1(){///
    String[] fields = new String[] {SQLDataBaseHelper.UID,SQLDataBaseHelper.NAME, SQLDataBaseHelper.NO, SQLDataBaseHelper.PICTURE};
    return fields;
}
public int[] toIds1(){
    int[] toViewIds = new int[]{R.id.contact_name,R.id.contact_no,R.id.contact_image};
    return toViewIds;
}



static class SQLDataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

     private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ContactsDataBase";
     private static final String TABLE1_NAME = "CALLS_TABLE1";
     private static final String TABLE2_NAME = "LOGS_TABLE";
     private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
     private static final String UID = "_id";
     private static final String NAME = "Name";
     private static final String NO = "ContactNo";
     private static final String DURATION = "Duration";
     private static final String PICTURE = "Picture";
     private static final String DATE = "Date";
     private static final String TIME = "Time";
     private static final String[] ALL_KEYS1 = new String[] {UID,NAME, NO, PICTURE};

     private static final String CREATE_TABLE1 =  "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE1_NAME+" (" +UID+
             " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+NAME+" VARCHAR(255), "+NO+" VARCHAR(255), "
             +PICTURE+" VARCHAR(255));";

     private static final String CREATE_TABLE2 =  "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE2_NAME+" ("
             +UID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+NAME+" VARCHAR(255), "+DURATION+" VARCHAR(255), "
             +PICTURE+" VARCHAR(255), " +DATE+ " VARCHAR(255), "+TIME+ " VARCHAR(255));";

     private static final String DROP_TABLE1 = "DROP TABLE  IF EXIST"+ TABLE1_NAME ;
     private static final String DROP_TABLE2 = "DROP TABLE  IF EXIST"+ TABLE2_NAME ;
     private Context context;


    public SQLDataBaseHelper (Context context) {           
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context = context;

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        try {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE1);
            Toast.makeText(context,"onCreate1 called" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Toast.makeText(context,""+e , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e("exception in onCreate", "here is exception  " + e);
        } //*/
        try {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE2);
            Toast.makeText(context,"onCreate2 called" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Toast.makeText(context,""+e , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e("exception in onCreate", "here is exception  " + e);
        } //*/
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        try {
            db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE1);
            Toast.makeText(context,"onUpgrade1 called" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            onCreate(db);
        }catch (SQLException e){
            Toast.makeText(context, ""+e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        try {
            db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE2);
            Toast.makeText(context,"onUpgrade2 called" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            onCreate(db);
        }catch (SQLException e){
            Toast.makeText(context, ""+e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

}
```

and these are the errors

```
01-30 04:03:23.804 2702-2702/com.example.asim.simpleviewpager E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main      
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x88a6fd
at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1049)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:664)
at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:323)
at android.support.v7.widget.TintManager.getDrawable(TintManager.java:175)
at android.support.v7.widget.TintManager.getDrawable(TintManager.java:168)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.setImageResource(AppCompatImageHelper.java:51)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageResource(AppCompatImageView.java:72)
at android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.setViewImage(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:195)
at android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.bindView(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:143)
```

Answer (score 1):

In SimpleCursorAdapter.java, you have a method bindView() which overrides the same method from its parent class, but you don't put any code in that method. Deleting the method should fix the error. But if you plan to override how binding works in that method, you may want to put some code in there starting with something like

```
super.bindView(view, context, cursor);
```

Comment: This answer helped solve a "Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x1" exception in a SimpleCursorAdapter.